# Syntax for this conditional expression

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code in an if else statement (c#).

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParentKey))
{
    Build(x => x.ParentKey == ParentKey);
}
else
{
    Build(x => x.Url == Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));
}
```

However, I would have preferred to use a condition expression like this:

```
var r = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParentKey)
          ? 100
          : 1000;
```

Normally, this wouldn't be an issue but the var is a `Func<SiloNode, bool>` meaning the expression would look like this:

```
Func<SiloNode, bool> predicate = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParentKey)
        ? x => x.ParentKey == ParentKey
        : x => x.Url == Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
```

Unsurprisingly, the code above gives me a syntax error but I'm not sure whether its because I'm using the wrong syntax or it is just not possible.

Anyone shed any light?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What you are doing certainly should be possible. The error you are getting will help us tell you what you need to fix...

Comment: Try     `Build(x => (string.IsNullOrEmptry(ParentKey)) ? 
        x.Url == Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) : 
        x.ParentKey == ParentKey);`

Comment: Didn't you miss to call the "Build" method in your 3rd piece of code?

Comment: Can you try `Build(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParentKey) ? (x.ParentKey == ParentKey) : (x.Url == Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)))`

Answer (score 1):

A lambda is just a lambda, and your two lambdas don't necessarily correspond to a `Func` object (even though the signatures match).

You can actually cast one (or both) of those lambdas into the appropriate `Func` type, and then the `?:` operator will work.

```
Func<SiloNode, bool> predicate = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParentKey)
    ? (Func<SiloNode, bool>)(x => x.ParentKey == ParentKey)
    : x => x.Url == Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
```

Comment: I wonder if there's a technical reason why it can't infer the types in the same way as it does if you just did `Func<SiloNode, bool> predicate =  x=>x.Url == "blah";` or if its just one of those things that didn't get assigned developer time...

Comment: Side note - this is a bit hard to read. I'd probably stick with an if/else here just to make it a little easier to read.

Comment: @Chris Probably the same reason you can't just say `var action = x => true;` or even `var action = (Foo x) => true;`- apparently lambdas can't be statically implicitly typed at runtime, even when it's obvious what the signature is. From what I can see, two delegate types, even with identical signatures, are not interchangeable, just like two classes with identical definitions are not interchangeable.

Comment: @JoeEnos - I see what you're saying Joe but if you use Zohar's version and format it, it looks readable.

Comment: You can use `Predicate<SiloNode>` instead `Func<SiloNode, bool> `

Comment: @JoeEnos: I'm not sure I'd agree its the same reason. In those examples you don't have enough information to decide between `Expression<Func<Foo,bool>>` and `Func<Foo,bool>` - either of them are valid. In the case of this question though you know the result has to be a `Func<SiloNode, bool>` so it feels much more plausible to do the same as the example in my first comment.

Comment: @smolchanovsky - nice idea but it doesn't work with the built in extension methods - for instance, SingleOrDefault();

Comment: @Chris Good point about `Expression`, but the ternary expression doesn't seem to know that the result has to be a `Func<SiloNode, bool>` rather than an `Expression`. You only know that because you see the left side of the `=`. But the ternary operator apparently only knows its own parts. Same situation with `object x = someBool ? "a" : 1;` which doesn't work unless you cast one of them to `object`. If the compiler was smarter, it would know that you're dumping the result into an `object` anyway, but I'm guessing it doesn't do that automatically because that could lead to unintentional casting.